# Separating rows and make the separations new columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am working with the riot API and have the following issue:

I have 3 columns that has a lot of data in the rows, that I need to split into columns. (Will only use 1 column as example, the others follow same structure)

The data for each row looks like this and this column is named 'teams'.

[{'teamId': 100, 'win': 'Fail'}] (the real rows are longer than this, but same structure)

So the data is separated by commas.

What I want the code to do is to wrangle the data like this:

| teamId | win |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Fail |

So the **data before the colon becomes the column** and the **data after the colon (but before the comma) becomes the row in my dataframe**.

I am new to python, but what I have tried is using the str.split function, but I could not manage to get it to work. It just returns NaN values for all rows.

```
df['teams'].str.split(",", expand = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using pandas.json_normalize on all your columns and then concat all results into to one. In your case it should be:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.json_normalize(df['teams'])
df2='same for 2nd column'
df3='same for 3nd column'

result=pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. when running `df1=pd.json_normalize(df['teams'])` I get the error message: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: It looks that your data is of type "list". You can change them to string and apply my solution. Tyr this and let me know if it works:
`df1=pd.json_normalize(df['teams'].astype(str))`

Comment: I could not make it your code work, when using it on the dataframe - however, when I used it prior to turning it into a dataframe, it worked, so thank you!

`normalize = pd.json_normalize(Jsonfile, 'teams')`